# Scanning uploaded files with Antivirus SDK

Tags: sdk, antivirus-integration

I'm creating a website with fileuploading functionality. I need to antivirus scan the files being uploaded. I'm currently running MS Forefront, but I don't know if it has builtin functionality for this purpose? Alternatively I need an AV SDK, but I don't really know any.

Any help on this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You could take a look at Kaspersky's SDK:
http://usa.kaspersky.com/partners/technology-alliances-partnerships/anti-virus-sdk

ClamAv also has a command line scanner which might suit your needs:
http://www.clamav.net/lang/en/

Answer (score 1):

There are some other options such as:

Microsoft Security Essentials: http://www.thewindowsclub.com/command-line-utility-for-microsoft-security-essentials

Avast (Pro): http://avast.helpmax.net/en/command-line-scanner/using-the-command-line/